# Grab objects in a top down game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, topdown

I want to do something like this but in top down: https://youtu.be/4zm8CvJPGb8. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Is your game 2D or 3D? Consider having a trigger collider as child of the player, and move it slightly forward in the player facing direction. Alternatively, do a CapsuleCast or Racyast hit check. Then to pick object, consider parenting it to the player, with a type of "held" reference to it in the player class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I would do exactly as the video you share does it, but the camera will be positioned at the top, using `Raycast`  instead of `Raycast2D`.